# What do the parentheses signify in (x:xs) when pattern matching?

Tags: haskell, syntax

when you split a list using x:xs syntax why is it wrapped in a parentheses? what is the significance of the parentheses? why not [x:xs] or just x:xs?

Comment: Do you have an example of where it is wrapped in ()?

x:xs can be used as is for describing a list with the list's first element. 
[x:xs] would be a list with the list x:xs in it.

Comment: He says about pattern matching, not about constructing list.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The cons cell doesn't have to be parenthesized in every context, but in most contexts it is because

## Function application binds tighter than any infix operator.

Burn this into your brain in letters of fire.

Example:

```
length [] = 0
length (x:xs) = 1 + length xs
```

If parentheses were omitted the compiler would think you had an argument `x` followed by an ill-placed infix operator, and it would complain bitterly.  On the other hand this is OK

```
length l = case l of [] -> 0
                     x:xs -> 1 + length xs
```

In this case neither `x` nor `xs` can possibly be construed as part of a function application so no parentheses are needed.

Note that the same wonderful rule **function application binds tighter than any infix operator** is what allows us to write `length xs` in `1 + length xs` without any parentheses.  The infix rule giveth and the infix rule taketh away.

Comment: +1 for letters of fire.  My Haskell code stopped looking like Lisp after I internalised this rule.

Comment: Thanks for specifying the difference with `case` expressions; I find that Standard ML -style syntax much more readable than having to carefully distinguish parentheses between meaning "tuples" vs "evaluation order"

Answer (score 15):

You're simply using the cons operator `:`, which has low precedence. Parentheses are needed so that things stay right.

And you don't use `[x:xs]`, because that would match a list whose only element is a list with head `x` and tail `xs`.

Comment: I had never tried that specific `[x:xs]` pattern, but of course you're right; it matches a singleton list on the top level. The desugared notation of the pattern would be: `((x:xs):[])`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know exact answer, but I guess that is due to what can be matched in patterns. Only constructors can be matched. Constructors can be of single word or composite. Look at the next code:

```
data Foo = Bar | Baz Int

f :: Foo -> Int
f Bar     = 1
f (Baz x) = x - 1
```

Single word constructors match as is. But composite constructors must be surrounded with parens in order to avoid ambiguity. If we skip parens it looks like matching against two *independent* arguments:

```
f Baz x = x - 1
```

So, as `(:)` is composite it must be in parens. Skipping parens for `Bar` is a kind of syntactic sugar.

UPDATE: I realized that (as sykora noted) it is a consequence of operator precedence. It clarifies my assumptions. Function application (which is just space between function and argument) has highest precedence. Others including (:) have lower precedence. So `f x:xs` is to be interpreted as `((:) (f x)) xs` that is presumably not what we need. While `f (x:xs)` is interpreted as `f` applied to `x:xs` which is in turn `(:)` applied to `x` and `xs`.

Answer (score 2):

It's to do with parsing.

Remember, the colon : is just a constructor that's written with operator syntax. So a function like

```
foo [] = 0
foo (x:xs) = x + foo xs
```

could also be written as

```
foo [] = 0
foo ((:) x xs) = x + foo xs
```

If you drop the parenthesis in that last line, it becomes very hard to parse!

Answer (score 1):

`:` is a data constructor, like any other pattern match, but written infix. The parentheses are purely there because of infix precedence; they're actually not required and can be safely omitted when precedence rules allow. For instance:

```
> let (_, a:_) = (1, [2, 3, 4]) in a
2
> let a:_ = "xyzzy"
'x'
> case [1, 2, 3] of; a:b -> a; otherwise -> 0;
1
```

Interestingly, that doesn't seem to work in the head of a lambda. Not sure why.

As always, the "juxtaposition" operator binds tighter than anything else, so more often than not the delimiters are necessary, but they're not actually *part* of the pattern match--otherwise you wouldn't be able to use patterns like `(x:y:zs)` instead of `(x:(y:zs))`.