# Haskell Matching pattern for lists

Tags: haskell

I'm very new to Haskell, and I decided to learn it some days ago, thanks to the haskell wikibook.

I'm reading at this moment the matching pattern for lists, but I can't understand the syntax for list.

Here's an example (from the wikibook) :

```
doubleList :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
doubleList [] = []
doubleList (n:ns) = (2 * n) : doubleList ns
```

I don't understand the part `(n:ns)`. How should I read it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can read it like this: `(head:tail)`, so if you have `[1, 2, 3]` and you match it with `(x:xs)`, then `x` will be bound to the first element in the list, `1`, and `xs` will be bound to the rest of the list, in this case `[2, 3]`.

Comment: why do we need parents when list pattern matching? Why simple `foo x:xs = undefined` leads us to `error: Parse error in pattern: foo`

Comment: ok, already found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191294/what-do-the-parentheses-signify-in-xxs-when-pattern-matching

Answer (score 3):

(:) is an operator with type `a->[a]->[a]`.  This means that it takes an item, and a list of those items, and returns another list of the same items.  The output list is formed by prepending the input item to the input list.

Here is how you can use it

```
1:[2,3]
```

will return

```
[1,2,3]
```

---

Because the (:) appears on the left hand side of the definition, in your case, you are pattern matching, and the operator is being used to deconstruct the value, rather than build it.

For example, if we have

```
func (first:rest) = ....
```

and call it like this

```
func [1,2,3]
```

the following values would be assigned

```
first=1 --notice, this is type a
rest=[2,3] --notice, this is type [a]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So the (:) function is called cons, isn't it ?
You say cons behaves differently when it is on the left on the declaration, is it a language feature ?

Comment: @MaximeB.- yes it is.  Actaully everything on the left of a definition behaves differently than the right (and it is very much a feature).  Left is for pattern matching, right is for output.  You can think of it a bit like a regex pattern match `/<pattern to match>/<output>/`.

Comment: note that `:` is a constructor, not a function. You can "unapply" constructors by pattern matching on them, but you can't unapply functions in the same way.

Comment: @rampion- Just to confuse matters more, I have to point out that constuctors are functions also....

Answer (score 3):

Another tip that might help you understand is by looking at the definition of the list data type:

```
data [] a = [] | a : ([] a)
```

Note that Haskell makes special syntax rules just for the list type, normally `[]` is not a valid constructor.  This definition is equivalent to

```
data List a = Empty | Cons a (List a)
```

Where

```
[] = Empty
(:) = Cons
```

You would pattern match on this as

```
doubleList :: List Int -> List Int
doubleList Empty = Empty
doubleList (Cons n ns) = Cons (2 * n) (doubleList ns)
```

If written using infix form:

```
doubleList (n `Cons` ns) = (2 * n) `Cons` doubleList ns
```

So now hopefully you can see the parallels between the two definitions.  Haskell also provides the special syntax rule that

```
[1, 2, 3, 4] = 1:2:3:4:[]
```

Since the former is much easier to write and read.  In fact, whenever you have a list literal like `[1, 2, 3, 4]` in your code, the compiler first converts it to `1:2:3:4:[]` before converting your code into an executable.