# (x:xs) pattern Haskell logic

Tags: haskell, cons

Let's say there is a simple function:

```
maximum' :: (Ord a) => [a] -> a  
maximum' [] = error "maximum of empty list"  
maximum' [x] = x  
maximum' (x:xs) = max x (maximum' xs)
```

I understand the idea and what (x:xs) does. As it was explained in details here 
[What do the parentheses signify in (x:xs) when pattern matching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191294/what-do-the-parentheses-signify-in-xxs-when-pattern-matching) 
but there is one little thing that I cannot get out of my head. Since *cons*: operator appends x to a list xs, **why is it that x is the first element of function argument list and xs is the tail when we use (x:xs)???** as if (x:xs) calls head and tail on argument list.

Comment: *"`:` operator appends x to a list xs"* - it doesn't; it appends `xs` to `x`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just an instance of the general pattern that the constructor for a type is both used to construct elements of that type and to deconstruct.  If you wrote

```
data MyList a = Empty | Cons a (MyList a)
```

you'd write

```
maximum' :: (Ord a) => MyList a -> a  
maximum' Empty = error "maximum of empty list"  
maximum' (Cons x Empty) = x  
maximum' (Cons x xs) = max x (maximum' xs)
```

Except that lists are actually defined equivalently to

```
data [a] = [] | a:as
```

so, just as with other data types, `:` is used both to construct and to deconstruct nonempty lists.

Comment: also worth noting [x] is syntactic sugar for x:[]

Answer (score 4):

The cons operator doesn't append, it prepends. That is `x : xs` produces a list that contains `x` as its first element and `xs` as the rest. Therefore the pattern `x : xs` likewise matches a list with `x` as the first element and `xs` as the rest.